# Best Practice for custom control of Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, custom-controls

I've searched a lot about creating a custom control for Google Maps Api v3, and I found others use it as 
[Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom). 
They create the divs and style it using JS, which I think is not a good practice.
I think this violates the separation of concerns design principle I mean, writing CSS code inside JS or HTML.

Apart from the best practise question, I've tried their code examples from the above link, but it doesn't work it raised the following error:

```
( **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zIndex' of undefined** ) ..
```

Here is the code for putting [**Zoom**] button.

**HTML file**

```
  <div id="control-div" class="control-div">
  <div id= "control-ui" class="control-ui" title = "Click to set the map to Home">
    <div id="control-text" class="control-text">
      <p> Zoom </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS file**

```
.control-ui{
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
}
.control-text{
  front-family: Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 4px 4px;
}
```

**JS file (Google map initializer)**

```
  var controlDiv =$("#control-div");
  var controlUI = $("#control-ui");
  var controlText = $("#control-text");
  controlUI.click(function() {
    map.setZoom(11);
  });
  controlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(controlDiv);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A control is expected to be a DOMNode, but you supply a jQuery-object.

This should work:

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(controlDiv[0]);
```

Comment: @Dr.Molle what about the best practises part? can you answer it?

Comment: Of course it's just my own opinion, but I would always prefer to apply the style via global CSS instead of setting it via JS. Especially for the custom controls, where a unique style (usually based on the style of the mapType-control) is  desirable, a global CSS should be preferable.

Comment: I've another question if possible, what does exactly controlDiv.index  mean ? what's its purpose?

Comment: It defines the order of the controls. By default at first the built-in controls will be placed at the ControlPosition, then the custom controls(in the order like they have been pushed into the array). Based on the example linked in your question the first control is the MapTypeControl(placed most right on the TOP of the map). The 2nd control is the Home-control, placed on the left side of  the mapTypeControl. When you define a `index` of `0` for the `homeControlDiv` the Home-Control will be the first control and the MapTypeControl will be placed on the left side of the Home-Control

Answer (score 1):

You certainly want to add your custom logos and copyrights to Google Maps via custom controls.  Otherwise, they will likely not render properly especially on mobile devices.

I found the official [Google Maps JavaScript API Custom Control example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomExample) to be rather complicated and I can never remember the position options.  So, I created a [tiny 1.72 KB add-on JS on GitHub](https://github.com/rhroyston/control-js) library called CONTROL-JS that enables you to simply create your custom content as a string, e.g., `var html = "<h1>Hi</h1>"` then pass it to an object called `control` where every position is a method (IDE intellisense reminds you of the possible positions).

So, in your case, unsing CONTROL-JS just do

```
var html = '<p id="control-text"> Zoom </p>'

//Global method that is fired when the API is loaded and ready
function initMap () {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    //intelleSense/Auto-complete works on IDE's
    control.topCenter.add(html);
};
```

[image]

```js
/*
control.js v0.1 - Add custom controls to Google Maps with ease
Created by Ron Royston, www.rack.pub
https://github.com/rhroyston/control
License: MIT
control.topCenter.add.(html)
*/
var control=function(){function o(o){this.add=function(T){var t=document.createElement("div");if(t.innerHTML=T,o)switch(o){case"TOP_CENTER":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(t);break;case"TOP_LEFT":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(t);break;case"TOP_RIGHT":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(t);break;case"LEFT_TOP":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(t);break;case"RIGHT_TOP":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(t);break;case"LEFT_CENTER":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER].push(t);break;case"RIGHT_CENTER":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER].push(t);break;case"LEFT_BOTTOM":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM].push(t);break;case"RIGHT_BOTTOM":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(t);break;case"BOTTOM_CENTER":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER].push(t);break;case"BOTTOM_LEFT":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].push(t);break;case"BOTTOM_RIGHT":map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT].push(t)}else console.log("err")}}var T={};return T.topCenter=new o("TOP_CENTER"),T.topLeft=new o("TOP_LEFT"),T.topRight=new o("TOP_RIGHT"),T.leftTop=new o("LEFT_TOP"),T.rightTop=new o("RIGHT_TOP"),T.leftCenter=new o("LEFT_CENTER"),T.rightCenter=new o("RIGHT_CENTER"),T.leftBottom=new o("LEFT_BOTTOM"),T.rightBottom=new o("RIGHT_BOTTOM"),T.bottomCenter=new o("BOTTOM_CENTER"),T.bottomLeft=new o("BOTTOM_LEFT"),T.bottomRight=new o("BOTTOM_RIGHT"),T}();
```